# what's the best practice to play video in a web page?

Tags: video

so as the title says,what's the best practice to play video in a web page.
and I have to consider the client's barrier-free experience.
thanks.

Comment: Embed youtube? Then it's somebody else's problem to maintain the best method.

Comment: @GregHewgill,no. I just want to play the files which are saved at the server-side.better to support flv/avi media formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use JWPlayer from http://www.longtailvideo.com/

Answer (score 1):

check out the cross browser compatible [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org) I've used it in a few projects.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used [SublimeVideo](http://sublimevideo.net/), to take advantage of their option to include a video playlist in a sidebar. The free version has a small watermark

While I was researching, I found these pages to be helpful:

http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/06/best-html5-media-player-implementations/

http://www.webmproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

I used [acorn media player](http://ghinda.net/acornmediaplayer/) and this  can be added in any web page.

These links will be useful::
http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody

https://github.com/ghinda/acornmediaplayer/issues?state=open